# Error: JVM could not create

Tags: gate

When I open GATE, I meet error "Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal execption has occurred. Program will exit". How to resovle??? Help me!

Answer (score 0):

At first step I suggest to delete your **App Data** of gate .

Comment: I had deleted it at C:\users\<username-PC> (example: .gate, gate.session, gate.xml,...). I reinstalled the GATE and JDK but It not effect.

Comment: what is version of your java? do you have jdk? have you installed it?

Comment: ohumm is it compatible with your windows? what version is it?

Answer (score 0):

Try rebooting the system and then run the GATE application, it will work fine.